# How do I send React Application context from non react class?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, bridge

I need to update status changes like event between android and react native class?

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
      @Override
      public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Push Message Received ");
        buildLocalNotification(remoteMessage);
      }

      public void buildLocalNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
        ...
        FBMessagingHelper notificationHelper = new FBMessagingHelper(this.getApplication());
        notificationHelper.showNotification(bundle);
      }
    }
```

How can I create a `ReactApplicationContext` constructor as class is extended to FBMessingService?

```
FBMessagingHelper notificationHelper = new FBMessagingHelper(this.getApplication());
// Getting Error as a parameter is not react app context
```

I need to update `IN_VIDEO_PROGRESS` status

1. Update to `Android` when video starts/stop by `React Native`.
2. Update to `React Native` when video starts/stop by `Android`.

```
public class FBMessagingHelper extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private ReactApplicationContext mContext;
  private static boolean IN_VIDEO_PROGRESS = false;

  public FBMessagingHelper(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) { // Added into Native Modules
     mContext = applicationContext;
  }

@ReactMethod
    public void onVideoProgress(Bolean status){
        // ==== on videoProgress ====
        IN_VIDEO_PROGRESS = status
    }

 @Nonnull
 @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "FBMessagingHelper";
    }

  public void showCustomNotification(Bundle bundle) {
    if (!IN_VIDEO_PROGRESS && bundle.getString("category").equals("VIDEO") {
       IN_VIDEO_PROGRESS = true;
       // start FullScreenNotificationActivity
    }
  }
}
```

Created Native Modules:

```
    public class FBMessagingPackage implements ReactPackage{
    @Override
      public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new FBMessagingHelper(reactContext));
        modules.add((NativeModule) new MessagingService(reactContext));
        // Error: cannot be cast to nativeModule
        return modules;
      }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have somehow solved this. we cannot extend `ReactApplicationContext` on `FirebaseMessagingService`. This service will be called even when app is not running and we don't have control to add react context.

So I have created a separate module and added the listeners which will update the event data to FBMessagingHelper class.

```
public class FBMessagingPackage implements ReactPackage{
    @Override
      public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new VideoModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
      }
    }
```

```
public class VideoModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
   private ReactApplicationContext mContext;

  public VideoModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) { // Added into Native Modules
     mContext = applicationContext;
  }

@ReactMethod
    public void onVideoProgress(Bolean status){
        FBMessagingHelper.IN_VIDEO_PROGRESS = status 
        // Store it to public static variable of FBMessagingHelper
    }

 @Nonnull
 @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "VideoModule";
    }


}
```